# Global UTF-encoding, the right way

Tags: css, javascript, html5, content-encoding

I'm curious, as to what is the right way to have UTF-8 encoding on all web files

**All my files (incl. CSS and JS) are made and saved in UTF-8 encoding**

In PHP, I set the char-set on top of the main page (this page includes all others) with:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

In the same page I have this html meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Then I stubled upon an external css file that has this on first line:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

And now I wonder, should I set the charset INSIDE all my CSS/JS files too, like that?

And/or should I serve each file with *charset=utf-8* in the meta tag?
UPDATE: Character encoding of the linked resource (charset="utf-8") is obsolete

Answer (score 2):

The best place for the character set declaration when served from your webserver is in the "Content-Type" header.     You are doing it correctly when serving it from PHP.   You could also set the header for CSS and JS.  Assuming that your CSS and JS are *not* served through PHP, but as static files, you could add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
AddCharset utf-8 .js
AddCharset utf-8 .css
```

When linking to to your JavaScript files from your HTML you can also include the character set there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/file.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The in body charset declarations are most useful for when your files get downloaded and opened locally.  In those cases meta information in the headers is lost.

Comment: Character encoding of the linked resource (charset="utf-8") is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the meta element setting utf-8 is so user's browsers can properly read the page should they save it to their desktop where a server won't be serving the page and include the utf-8 header. In PHP, you set it in the header which actually makes including it in the page redundant (and repetitive, too :) ) but a good idea for the reason I gave.

I've forgotten what the @charset would be for but I've never used it which shows how important including that is.

btw, meta tags do not have a closing slash.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't need the closing tag in meta tags, but it's perfectly ok to do it.. You made me read up on it :)

Comment: @mowgli If you read up on it, you'll find you're right. It's now allowed but 1) it's not needed 2) browsers ignore it 3) it doesn't affect anything in any way 4) it only takes up space and data on the wire and therefore 5) is totally useless. Remove it and quit using it.

Comment: Yeah I removed it :) Damn, I thought HTML5 would be more precise "THIS is correct". Anyway, overall things are much better now than 10-15 years ago

Comment: @mowgli Well, if you look at the spec, nowhere will you find them ever mentioning using the closing slash, and it's not in any of the examples, except under "void elements". iirc, that is where it says you can do that but it's pointless.